# Cloudflare Origin Server Exposing IP with DNS Only SRV Record

Tags: web-server, cloudflare

I have a domain registered with Cloudflare with an associated A record which point to the IP of my server (origin server), as well as an A record for a subdomain (service1.example.com) for a TCP protocol service. Both of these A records are proxied with Cloudflare. I have also set up an SRV record which points this subdomain to the specific port hosting the service on the origin server. This is DNS only. I acknowledge Cloudflare does not proxy such protocols (with the free option). My question is in regards to Cloudflare's following warning next to the record type:

```
This record exposes the IP address used in the A record on service1.example.com, which you have proxied through Cloudflare.
```

If I were to ping this subdomain using the `dig` command, for example, I would see Cloudflare's IP. How would one find the true origin IP as Cloudflare warns?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare is letting you know that you have a record that proxies (hides) an ip address, but another record (it sounds like your srv record) that exposes that same ip address.

If your intention is to hide your origin IP entirely, then you should either host the site on a different server with a different ip than the srv record ip, or use something like Cloudflare spectrum to proxy the non http services through Cloudflare’s network.

If you’re worried about price, TCPShield https://tcpshield.com and Lectron https://www.lectron.com both resell Cloudflare Soecturm for a lot less than Cloudflare’s official price, but of course, that’s just one solution.